# in html store python variable in another variable

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
 {% for position in positions %}
       {% if position['symbol'] != 'CASH' %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{position['symbol']}}</td>
              <td>{{position['name']}}</td>
              <td>{{position['shares']}}</td>
              <td>{{position['price']}}</td>
              <td>{{position['total']}}</td>
          </tr>
       {% else %}
          {% cash = position['total'] %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{cash}}</td>
          </tr>  

       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to capture 'cash' and use it later in the html?

Comment: thanks, did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:  `{% set variable = cash %}`

Comment: Now variable = cash